# How to update React component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a child object (element of list) which is rendered inside(?) the parent one. The component has the following properties (from JSON):

```
contract
{
  id,
  name,
}
```

But I need to add another one additional property which is filled in after an HTTP request with an external function to the API (for example, `uuid`) using one of the existing properties of an object.
My current React code looks the following way (only child component is provided):

```
class Contract extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: this.props.contract};
    getUuidByName(this.state.data.name).then(val => {
      this.state.data.uuid = val;
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){ }

  render() {
    return <tr>
      <td>{this.state.data.id}</td>
      <td>{this.state.data.name}</td>
      <td>{this.state.data.uuid}</td>
    </tr>
  }
}
```

Everything rendered good except an additional property: `uuid`. Of course I do something wrong or don't do some important thing, but I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating state in the constructor. ***Never mutate state directly.*** If you are needing to set/initialize some state ***after*** it's been constructed, or mounted, then you should use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. Ensure you enqueue the state update via the `this.setState` method.

```
class Contract extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: props.contract,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getUuidByName(this.state.data.name).then(val => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        data: {
          ...prevState.data,
          uuid: val,
        },
      }));
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){ }

  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.state.data.id}</td>
        <td>{this.state.data.name}</td>
        <td>{this.state.data.uuid}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Do not modify state directly.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Because you're directly modifying the state, React isn't triggering a re-render.

Try the following in your constructor instead:

```js
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {data: this.props.contract};
  getUuidByName(this.state.data.name).then(val => {
    this.setState({
      data: {
        ...this.state.data,
        uuid:  val
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Can't call `this.setState` in the [constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it works excellent!

Comment: @DrewReese Oh yeah, forgot about that...Been a while since I've used class components.

Comment: Well, I guess you *technically* are still calling it in the constructor, but the asynchronous nature of the Promise chain is allowing it to work, likely because the component is mounted by then.